# How to docker registry mirrors if I have multiple?

Tags: docker

There is a configuration named `registry-mirrors` in `daemon.json`, How would the pull behaves if I have multiple registry-mirros？will it search the image in the appearance order while pulling an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the offical documentation,

**How does it work?**

> The first time you request an image from your local registry mirror,
>   it pulls the image from the public Docker registry and stores it
>   locally before handing it back to you. On subsequent requests, the
>   local registry mirror is able to serve the image from its own storage.

**[Using Container Registry's Docker Hub mirror](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/using-dockerhub-mirroring)**

> The Docker daemon checks the Container Registry registry and fetches
>   the images if it exists. You can have multiple mirrors configured, for
>   example you may also have your own local mirror. The Docker daemon
>   will **check each configured mirror for the image until it is found.**

[using-dockerhub-mirroring](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/using-dockerhub-mirroring)